# Build an Xcode project on a Linux machine

Tags: objective-c, linux, cocoa, xcodebuild, gnustep

Without writing a GNUmakefile by hand, do any tools exist that understand Xcode projects and can build them directly against GNUstep, producing a Linux executable, thus simplifying (slightly) the work required to keep projects functional under Cocoa/Mac and GNUstep/Linux?

Basically, is there an xcodebuild style app for Linux?

I looked at pbtomake a few weeks ago but it seems to be a dead project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easier to build yourself a set of compilers and binutils that run on OS X but target linux.

Comment: Or use a Linux VM on Mac OS X

Comment: Doesn't using a Linux VM on Mac OS X just leave me back at the original question?  What difference does it make where the Linux install is?

Comment: Crosscompiling on Mac OS means you can still use xcodebuild EVEN to build the Linux executable.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use [GNUstep pbxbuild](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Pbxbuild) which is different from the the Mac OS X one. I am not sure how fully featured it is but it's surely worth to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need to look at [cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/).  It lets you use a subset of Cocoa and compile for OS X, Windows and Linux.  It's not GNUstep, but it does seem to work for the things I've tried it with.  Compiling is done from inside Xcode, so it's not 100% what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to just ssh to a proper OS X machine and do the build there (using xcodebuild).

Comment: Sorry, I may not have explained correctly.  The app will sometimes be built to run on Linux itself, and other times it will be built to run on Mac.  It isn't the case that it will always be installed to a Mac; thus the code needs to be compiled for Linux sometimes.  The Linux machine would have GNUstep installed on it. It would be nice to be able to rsync the entire project to the linux box and have some sort of xcodebuild run there, resulting in a linux executable, not the other way around.

Comment: It's probably easier to do it the other way round - set up a Linux VM on your Mac and then do both the Linux build and the OS X build on the Mac. This is what I do for cross-platform code (I use VMware Fusion so that I have WIN32 and Linux x86-64 VMs running on my Mac).